# saving the data using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to save four fields on click one is textbox two checkboxes and one wysihtml5Editor using ajax these are the as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" required title="required" placeholder="title" data-bind="value:title" />
<input type="checkbox" id="active" name="active" class="check" data-bind="checked: active=='true'"  />Active
<input type="checkbox" id="logon" name="logon" class="check" data-bind="checked: use_logo=='true'"  />Logo
<textarea id="iiii" name="iiii" class="htmleditor" rows="9" cols="50" style="width: 600px; height: 190px;"></textarea>
<button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

my table name is `contracts` and the field name are as follows:

```
title(textbox),def_next(wysihtml5Editor),active(checkbox),use_logo(checkbox)
```

and i am doing it at the condition as follows:

```
if ($_POST['what']=="save"){}
```

and i have tried ajax as

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: root + 'data/comapanydata_contractorslist?json',
        data: {
            what: "save",
            text: $('#iiii').val(),
            def_text: def_text
        },
        success: function (data) {},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

but not working so please suggest me on this.

Comment: What is not working, mishraji?

Comment: "Not working" as in a JS or PHP error, or...?

Comment: Show a code which is inside of `if ($_POST['what']=="save"){}`.

Comment: no i am beginner in php and i want to save it using ajax since i don't have an idea how to save using ajax?

Comment: it would be query for inserting the data into the database.like if ($_POST['what']=="save"){
 $def_text=$_POST['def_text'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$SALES.".contracts (title,def_text) VALUES ('$title','$def_text')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $model["save"]=$sql;
}

Comment: Oh are you doing `form submit` in jquery?

Comment: What is the `def_text` variable? Please click "edit" and add the PHP code from your previous comment and more of your JS to the question.

Comment: Check this example how ajax with php http://zwaroop.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/insert-data-into-mysql-using-php-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save all 4 fields, you need to transfer data from all of them to your server side script. Maybe something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: root + 'data/comapanydata_contractorslist?json',
    data: {
        what: "save",
        def_text: $('#iiii').val(),
        title: $('#title').val(),
        active: $('#active').val(),
        use_logo: $('#logon').val()
    },
    success: function (data) {},
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

index.html

```
            <script>
            $(function() {                  
                $("#form").submit(function() {
                    data = $("#form").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : "save-data.php",
                        data : data,
                        success : function() {
                            $("#form").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("")
                            $("#form").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false); 
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
            </script>

            <form action="save-data.php" method="get" id="form">
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required title="required" placeholder="title" data-bind="value:title" />
                <input type="hidden" name="active" value="off" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="active" name="active" class="check" data-bind="checked: active=='true'" />Active                 
                <input type="hidden" name="logon" value="off" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="logon" name="logon" class="check" data-bind="checked: use_logo=='true'" />Logo
                <textarea id="iiii" name="iiii" class="htmleditor" rows="9" cols="50" style="width: 600px; height: 190px;"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </form>
```

Saving inputs to variables:

save-data.php

```
        <?php 
            $required = array('title', 'iiii', 'active', 'logon');
            $error = false;
            foreach ($required as $field) {
                if (empty($_GET[$field])) {
                    $error = true;
                }
            }

            if (isset($_GET["title"])) {
                if ($error) {
                    echo "All fields are required.";
                } else {
                    $title = $_GET["title"];
                    $active = $_GET["active"];
                    $logon = $_GET["logon"];
                    $iiii = $_GET["iiii"];

                       //mysql query ...
                }
            }
        ?>
```